# Reversing a string with no stringbuilder and user input?

Tags: java

Hi I have to create a program that can take a string that a user inputs through a input box and display the string in reverse in a output box. I also can't use StringBuilder. Before I knew that, I was able to do this using StringBuilder

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

public class reverse 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     String string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a string");

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString());

   }
}`
```

So after I found out that I can't use StringBuilder I tried to reprogram this and this is the code I came up with

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 
public class reversethisstring
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
     String reverseMe = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a string");
for (int i = 0; i < reverseMe.length(); i++) {
    reverseMe = reverseMe.substring(1, reverseMe.length() - i)
        + reverseMe.substring(0, 1)
        + reverseMe.substring(reverseMe.length() - i, reverseMe.length());
 }
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(reverseMe);
   }
}
```

Now I am getting a error on line 12 that says 
"The method showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component, java.lang.Object) in the type javax.swing.JOptionPane is not applicable for the arguments (java.lang.String)"

The code worked fine when I used "system.out.println" on the last line instead of the JOptionPane. So how can I convert this to work in a output box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the mentioned `showMessageDialog(null, reverseMe);` here's anoher go at reversing the `String` that uses the fact that `String`s are build from `char[]`s.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input a string");
   String reversed = reverse(string);
   showMessageDialog(null, reversed); 
}

private static String reverse(String forward) {
    char[] x = forward.toCharArray();
    String reversed = "";
    for(int i = x.length-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        reversed += x[i];
    }
    return reversed;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

showMessageDialog takes two arguments, the first one being a Component. You can fix your code by just passing in null:

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, reverseMe);`

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this line:

```
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(reverseMe);
```

To some thing like this:

```
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, reverseMe, "Title", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Or like this:

```
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, reverseMe);
```